# How do I go through UK immigration with my young child who has a visa while I have a British passport?

Tags: airports, children

I will soon be traveling to the UK with my very young (as in not quite walking yet) child who is an Indian citizen. I have a British passport. We'll be arriving at London Stansted. I've been there before and I know there are separate lines at the border for processing British passports (with automated passport scanning gates) and other country visas, and I'm just wondering how one is supposed to handle this situation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UK Gov [state](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/at-border-control) :

> You must:
>
> - [...]
> - move through passport control together if you’re in a family

> #### If you’re a British citizen
>
> You can use the UK/EEA channel to get your passport or Gibraltar
> identity card checked - this is usually faster than the other
> channels.
>
> You can use automatic ePassport gates at some airports if your
> passport has a ‘chip’ on it and you’re 12 or over. If you’re between
> 12 and 17, you must be accompanied by an adult.
>
> These gates use facial recognition technology to check your identity
> against the photo in your passport.

You would go into the UK/EEA channel and be guided through to a manned counter.

Depending on the queues on arrival, you can also go to the Other Passports line without issues.

Comment: > You would go into the UK/EEA channel and be guided through to a manned counter.

Does that apply if the child is not British though? My reading of this was that they would have to go to the non-UK/EEA channel, but I could easily be wrong.

Comment: @Leaderboard Yes, this applies, family must not be separated and, as a UKC you are eligible for the UK/EEA channel, you can go through that channel (this is the rule basically everywhere, a USC family can definitely go with the USC through the USC channel, same in the EU)

Comment: Does this apply only to children (i.e, does this apply if it's just a couple)?

Comment: @Leaderboard Family (on an immigration standpoint) is *usually* (very dependent), your (either married or *de-facto*) spouse, unmarried children (and sometimes it can involve your parents or your siblings). For a border control, all of those would very likely qualify as family

Comment: As an EEA citizen, I have been turned away from the UK/EEA channel on three occasions when travelling with my non-EEA spouse. @NicolasFormichella Can you give a reference that confirms your statement "You would go into the UK/EEA channel and be guided through to a manned counter"? My reading of the two references you give does not confirm this. My reading of the references you give would tell me to move together as a family, using the "All other passports" queue.